# Find and replace text in an input field

Tags: javascript, php, forms, joomla, date-formatting

I have a joomla registration form (using the easyprofile joomla component) with a date field (calendar date picker) which put the date in the following format:

31-12-2016

Id like to change the format of this date to:

31-Dec-2016

I wondered if this is possible with php or even js to find and replace the string in this field, something like the following:

FIND: -01- 
REPLACE: -Jan-

FIND: -02- 
REPLACE: -Feb-

This would have to work instantly as soon as the user selects or changes the date from the calendar.

Many thanks in advance is anyone can help!

Comment: Could you [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/38542562/edit) to include what have you tried?

Comment: I haven't im unsure how to achieve this, and my research hasn't uncovered anything that would work, I was hoping someone might know here? :)

Comment: "This would have to work instantly as soon as the user selects or changes the date from the calendar." Jquery or Js is what you need in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

Split the string, find the month by index, recreate the date and add as value.

[JQUERY]

```
var months = ['Jan','Feb','May','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'];

// You can also use the classname or id to select the element.
// var element = $('.classname');
var element = $('input[name="jform[moving_date]"]');

element.on('change', function(e) {

    // You might need to stop propagation but this will cause other scripts from firing like date picker.
    // e.stopPropagation();

    var date_parts = $(this).val().split('-');
    var month_index = Number(date_parts[1]) - 1;
    var date_new = date_parts[0] + '-' + months[month_index] + '-' + date_parts[2];
    $(this).val(date_new);
});
```

Comment: Many many thanks @Nitin! My input field is named `jform[moving_date]` I think its causing a syntax error having the square brackets twice ie `var element = $('input[name=jform[moving_date]]');` as currently I cant seem to get it to work. Thanks again! :)

Comment: @jimmywiddle updated my answer. You can also use the classname or id to select the element. http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_selectors.asp

Comment: many thanks for that.. very much appreciated!!!! but im sorry to say its still not working for me :( any ideas what i might be doing wrong? :(

Comment: Try the function with e.stopPropagation(); if it works, you might need to add a timeout function but this would a hack.